# Pagination links is not show when using paginate in laravel

Tags: laravel, pagination

So I have some problem in here, the links is not shown on my output data, I have try made query like this :

```
$getData = Inventory::select('id_inventory', 'inventory_code', 'inventory_id_location', 'inventory_id_category', 'date_of_buy', 'price_of_item', 'condition_of_item', 'description', 'created_by', 'edited_by')
                ->selectRaw('group_concat(inventory_id_category) as inventory_id_categories')
                ->selectRaw('group_concat(id_inventory) as id_inventories')
                ->with(['categories' => function ($query) {
                    $query->select('id_category', 'category_code', 'category_name');
                }])
                ->with(['locations' => function ($query) {
                    $query->select('id_location', 'location_name');
                }])
                ->with(['delivery_inventories' => function ($query) {
                    $query->select('id_delivery', 'delivery_id_inventory', 'delivery_id_location', 'delivery_date', 'deliver_by', 'description')
                    ->with(['location_deliveries' => function ($query) {
                        $query->select('id_location', 'location_name');
                    }]);
                }])
                ->whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($search) {
                    $query->orWhere('category_code', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                        ->orWhere('category_name', 'like', "%{$search}%");
                })
                ->whereHas('locations', function ($query) use ($search) {
                    $query->orWhere('location_name', 'like', "%{$search}%");
                })
                ->whereHas('delivery_inventories', function ($query) use ($search) {
                    $query->orWhere('delivery_date', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                        ->orWhere('deliver_by', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                        ->orWhere('description', 'like', "%{$search}%");
                })
                ->where('inventory_code', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                ->orWhere('price_of_item', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                ->orWhere('condition_of_item', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                ->orWhere('description', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                ->groupBy('inventory_code')
                ->orderBy('inventory_code')
                ->paginate(10);

        return response()->json([
            'get_data' => $getData
        ], 200);
```

but on my console the result like this :

[image]

I wanna ask any wrong or something uncompleted query so that's my links doesn't show up on my console? Any suggest? Thank you.

my project before (but I can't use that in my current project) :

[image]

Comment: `next_page_url` and `last_page_url` look like the pagination links to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: Any info you need for pagination is in this JSON - build your pagination based on that info. There will be no "Prev", "Next", 1,2,3... links in JSON

Comment: @apokryfos, I already updated my question I hope my question will be more have clear explanation

Comment: @brombeer, no sir in my previous project I can use that the links, but now I can't use that

Comment: It looks like `links` was added in Laravel 8.0.3 so it's possible this project is older?

Comment: omg you're right sir, my current project is having more older version then my previous version, I'm so sorry I didn't realize it :(

Comment: Have you tried creating the API resource ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your AppServiceProvider?
if not go to app/providers/AppServiceProvider.php
and add paginator in there.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Paginator::useBootstrap();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggest sir, but should I to update the `AppServiceProvider` like your own? Because on previous project I didn't make a change in that file

Comment: this change happened in laravel 8.  add the paginator in appserviceprovider and test it. if not working you can delete it

Comment: I already try, but something error show sir, my error like this `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::useBootstrap()` what should I do?

Comment: use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator; you added this line too,right?

Comment: yes I do sir, but the error still show

Comment: if there is no items available for page 2 ,laravel will not generate pagination lkinks.  
is $getData having more than 10 items in it ?

Comment: yes have it sir, my data is more than 10 items in my database

Comment: dd($getData->links()); in controller before sending response and check if pagination urls available in data->elements->array

Comment: He is returning the data as json resposne. So  ```Paginator::useBootstrap();```` has nothing to do with this

Comment: well, I already done with my problem, the problem is I must update my laravel project to laravel 8 but my current project version is using laravel 7, thanks all